Proving that solutions to $\cos p\theta+\cos q\theta=0$ form two arithmetical progressions, with differences $\frac{2\pi}{p+q}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{p-q}$
From S. L. Loney

If $\cos p\theta + \cos q\theta = 0$, prove that the different values of $\theta$ form two arithmetical progressions in which the common differences are $\frac{2\pi}{p+q}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{p-q}$ respectively.

I first got that $$\cos p\theta = \cos(\pi \pm q\theta)$$ and then converting to general form $$2n\pi \pm p\theta = 2n\pi \pm (\pi \pm q\theta)$$
Here, I had a nagging feeling that I should be using two different variables for the general value of $p\theta$ and $q\theta$ but I couldn't explain to myself why. I got stuck here. I would really appreciate some help.

Also, in the textbook, only radian measure and things like $\cos(\pi+\theta) = -\cos(\theta)$ have been done. And heights and distances, but that isn't useful here.

The solution to $\cos p\theta = \cos(\pi \pm q\theta)$ is $p\theta = 2n\pi \pm (\pi \pm q\theta)$. Why have you written $2n\pi$ on LHS?

@not_a_math_guy But since $p\theta$ is a constant and the R.H.S is not, how would that work?

If $p$ and $q$ are constants then both LHS and RHS are constant for a particular value of $n$. $n$ on RHS will corresponds to different solutions of the equations since after adding any multiple of $2\pi$ solution wouldn't change.

@AkshajMishra check my answer — I've modified it to your requirements.

If you use the trigonometric identity:
$$\cos(\alpha) + \cos(\beta) \equiv 2\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)$$
then, the given equation transforms into:
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{p + q}{2}\theta\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{p - q}{2}\theta\right) = 0$$
All that's left is case work, which I trust you with...
If you feel uncomfortable with this identity, then, here's how you could proceed:
$$\cos(p\theta) = \cos(π ± q\theta) \Longrightarrow p\theta = π ± q\theta + 2πn$$
You need not add a multiple of $2π$ on the LHS because, if you did:
$$p\theta + 2πn_1 = π ± q\theta + 2πn_2 \Longrightarrow p\theta = π ± q\theta + 2π\left(n_2 - n_1\right) \equiv π ± q\theta + 2πn$$
Essentially, all the multiples of $2π$ can be submitted collectively to a single side. Now you get:
$$(p ± q)\theta = π + 2πn \Longrightarrow \boxed{\therefore\theta = \dfrac{π}{p±q} + \dfrac{2π}{p ± q}n}$$
Clearly, we've obtained an A.P. for $\theta$ as per the question.

can you explain further?

@AkshajMishra
This is very much like a quadratic. Either:
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\theta\right) = 0$$
or:
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{p-q}{2}\theta\right) = 0$$
All you need to use is the general idea that the solutions to $x$ in $\cos(x) = 0$ is $x = π + 2πn$, where $n$ is any integer.

ok. thanks. can you give another solution that involves general values?

@AkshajMishra to be honest, this is the fastest solution that I can think of.

I get that, but I want to solve it the textbook way without using advanced concepts that haven't been taught in the textbook yet

so my mistake is assuming that $p\theta$ is constant? because $\theta$ has multiple (infinite) values

@AkshajMishra sure $p\theta$ is not a constant. While $p$ may be a constant, it seems that we're solving for $\theta$, so $p\theta$ is not a constant.
However, I'd say that your main flaw was writing:
$$2πn ± p\theta = 2πn ± (π ± q\theta)$$
where the $2πn$ terms cancel out on both sides.

@JoydeepBepari okay, tell me, is it logical to write this? what should be your train of thought? Can we jump directly to your statement without this one? $2n\pi \pm p\theta = 2m\pi \pm (\pi \pm q\theta)$
I am sorry if I have troubled you a lot, but all this is to resolve my doubt.
